# Linux du directory size, how is this possible?

Tags: linux, diskspace

I have a folder called joblibSCRATCH.  I do and see this

```
ubuntu@memo:~$ du -s joblibSCRATCH
2831128 joblibSCRATCH
```

This is 2831128 kilobytes, which is 2.836024GB.  I then do and see this

```
ubuntu@memo:~$ du -hs joblibSCRATCH
2.7G    joblibSCRATCH
```

So du is saying that this folder is both 2.7GB and 2.83 GB.  How can this be?  If it makes any difference I'm using a virtual hard drive on a cloud server.

Comment: 2831128 is not 2.83GB. (Well, actually, is if you believe SI, but GB was originally non-SI, and most IT people will never call it GiB.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 2831128 / 1024 = 2764.7734375
 2764.7734375 / 1024 = 2.69997406005859375
```

Comment: Lol wow that's a duh right there.  Guess I shouldn't just plug stuff into Google without thinking.  I can't accept the answer yet so will do so tomorrow.